# How to remove &nbsp from TextView

Tags: android

I need to substitute `&nbps` in `TextView`. I can simply use `String.replace()`, but there might be better solution?

Comment: `String.replace()` is the only way of getting rid of these issues :)

Comment: you can set Html.fromHtml(string) to textview and check.

Comment: Html.fromHtml(String) works perfect for me, please answer so I can accept.

Comment: Unless you have other HTML that you are trying to interpret, using `fromHtml()` to replace `&nbsp;` with a space is like swatting a fly with a Buick. `replaceAll()` should be cheaper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try as using Pattern.compile:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&nbps");
String tempstr = "I love &nbps  &nbps.";

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(tempstr);
String tmp = matcher.replaceAll("Android");
```

you can see this post about performance of String.replace and matcher.replace

[String replaceAll() vs. Matcher replaceAll() (Performance differences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466959/string-replaceall-vs-matcher-replaceall-performance-differences)

Comment: So what a difference in performance wise with `String.replace()` ?

Comment: @AliImran : i don't now about performance of this piece of code but i'm sure this will work in all cases

Comment: an this is another way for replacing substring in current string

Comment: I know this before but i never give it preference over simple `String.replace()` method :)

Comment: @AliImran : in some cases String.replace() not worked then you  have this only option . and you can see my edit answer

Comment: Ya you are right, because some times `String.replace()` not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this function:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            mDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your Text", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        } else {
            mDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your Text"));
        }
```