# Getting non shorted UUID from the MOJANG api is not possible?

Tags: api, minecraft, uuid

When i try to convert a username to a UUID using the mojang api, the response allways is in the {"username":username, "id":shortened UUID of the username} format. but my problem is, i need the UUID of the player for another API which requires a non shortened UUID, and gives a "malformed UUID" error when i try to do the request with a short UUID. the basic difference between short and long UUID's in minecraft is that the long one's contain multiple - whilst the short ones dont. Is there any way to convert that or another endpoint?

Comment: Are you saying the only difference is literally the dashes, and there's the same number of other characters in the same places in both otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Mojang does not provide any endpoints to use dashed UUIDs instead, however there are many answers on how to insert dashes into the UUID. See [Creating a UUID from a string with no dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986712/creating-a-uuid-from-a-string-with-no-dashes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringBuilder#insert(int, char)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,char)) to insert dashes where they should be, it should look like this:

```
new StringBuilder("005056963AB75FD48BDC59C100314C40")
        .insert(20, '-')
        .insert(16, '-')
        .insert(12, '-')
        .insert(8, '-')
        .toString();
```