# replaceAll() vs. replaceAll(..., Matcher.quoteReplacement)

Tags: java, matcher, replaceall

Hello :D short question: What is the difference between

```
String geb = tf_datum.getText();
String sep = ""; //sep is short for seperator

geb = geb.replaceAll("\\.", sep);
geb = geb.replaceAll("\\,", sep); 
geb = geb.replaceAll("\\-", sep);
geb = geb.replaceAll("\\ ", sep);`
```

and

```
String geb = tf_datum.getText();

String sep = "";
geb = geb.replaceAll("\\.", Matcher.quoteReplacement(sep));
geb = geb.replaceAll("\\,", Matcher.quoteReplacement(sep)); 
geb = geb.replaceAll("\\-", Matcher.quoteReplacement(sep));
geb = geb.replaceAll("\\ ", Matcher.quoteReplacement(sep));
```

Because both is functionating. I tried to understand each method (in the second one) and to put it together but it makes no sense. 
If somebody can help me, that would be very nice!
Thanks. :)  (and I also found the other question  [which seems to be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466959/string-replaceall-vs-matcher-replaceall-performance-differences), but he did not use the Matcher.quote inside of the replaceAll() ... so I was not shure if it is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Matcher` case, you are doing some extra work that is not necessary, but it still effectively does the same thing (but I would assume you pay an efficiency price, though it would be negligible in this case).

In the first case, you do `geb.replaceAll("\\.", "")`. So you are saying take `geb`, and replace every period with 'nothing' essentially.

In the second case, you do `geb.replaceAll("\\.", Matcher.quoteReplacement(sep))`. Now, you are saying, take `geb` and replace every period with the return value of `Matcher.quoteReplacement("")`. In this case, `Matcher.quoteReplacement` returns `""`, exactly what you put into it. So it is essentially an extra/useless call that is not needed. Take a look at the docs for `Matcher.quoteReplacement` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)).

And for `String.replaceAll` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

The one thing it does mention here though is to use `quoteReplacement` to suppress the special meaning of control characters like `"\"` and `"$"`. So you only need to use that if you want the replacement `String` (the second argument to `replaceAll`) to behave as if those are literal characters and not control characters.

Also of note, you can do this all in one regex like `geb.replaceAll("[\\-\\,\\.\\s]", "");`. I think there are even better ways than that to do it but my regex isn't great.

Comment: thank you :) It makes sense and your device with "geb.replaceAll("[\\-\\,\\.\\s]", ""); " is working and the code looks a lot better now!