# Is scalas pattern matching regex thread safe?

Tags: regex, scala

Similar to [Is Java Regex Thread Safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360113/is-java-regex-thread-safe), I would like to know if this usage of scala regex is really thread safe? Are multiple threads able to call m on the same object M without interfering with each other in the result?

```
object R {
  val pat = """a(\d)""".r
}

class M {

  def m(s: String): Option[Int] = {
     s match {
       case R.pat(i) => Some(i.toInt)
       case _ => None
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are more than one class. It breaks down to:

- `scala.util.matching.Regex`
  depends on `java.util.regex.Pattern`, so, according to JavaDoc, thread-safe.
- `scala.util.matching.Regex.Match`
  depends on `java.util.regex.Match`, so, according to JavaDoc, **not thread-safe**.
- `scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchIterator`
  is mutable, and contains `java.util.regex.Match`, so **not thread-safe**.
- `scala.util.matching.Regex.MatchData`
  is technically thread-safe, but it only appears as part of the two classes above, so you won't find thread-safe instances of `MatchData`.

Comment: So what?  Do you think method m is thread-safe or not?  I think it is, because the Match objects and the MatchIterator objects are not shared by the threads calling m.

Comment: @StefanEndrullis I think calling m above is safe for the reasons you mention.

Answer (score 7):

Since Scala's support for regular expressions builds on top of java.util.regex.Pattern, and since instances of that class are threadsafe, I guess the answer is: *yes*:

It uses java.util.regex.Pattern:

```
class Regex(regex: String, groupNames: String*) extends Serializable {

  import Regex._

  /** The compiled pattern */
  val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)
```

According to the JavaDoc on Pattern, java.util.regex.Pattern is threadsafe:

> Instances of this class are immutable and are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads.

Comment: Just remember that although the `Pattern` is thread-safe, any `Matcher` instances obtained from the `Pattern` are not and must be treated as such. The OPs code is safe though.

Comment: Suppose I create a `Matcher` and then pass it to multiple threads. Is it threadsafe for each thread to make its own `clone()` of the Matcher and only use the clone?