# Kotlin Regex thread-safety

Tags: regex, kotlin, thread-safety

In Java, `Pattern` class is [thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360113/is-java-regex-thread-safe) all right.
But is Kotlin `Regex` (created like `"[ABC]+".toRegex()`) thread-safe on the JVM and other runtimes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`Regex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html) points you to [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the JVM.  So it will inherit `Pattern`'s concurrency behaviour.

(Note that checking the current implementation isn't enough; JetBrains can and do change their implementations.  But if it's specified in the docs, then it's part of the public API and should be fairly reliable.)

The corresponding docs for JavaScript point [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), which doesn't mention anything about thread-safety.  And that for Native doesn't even have a link.  So it's probably not safe to assume anything about them.

Comment: It is safe to assume that synchronous function calls in JavaScript are thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin [`toRegex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-regex.html) is just an extension function that creates a [`Regex`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html) object. On Kotlin/JVM that just calls `Pattern.compile(pattern)`, so the underlying code comes from the JDK and is thread-safe.